# I'm trying to store the email of the user into the localstorage so i can get it from every component but it doesn't work

Tags: angular, laravel

In the login component I'm trying to store the email of the user into the local storage:

```js
handleResponse(data){
    this.Token.handle(data.access_token);
    this.Auth.changeAuthStatus(true);
    this.service.senddata(this.user);
    localStorage.setItem('email',this.user.email);//this line is important
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/profile');
  }
```

In the navbar component I'm trying to get the email but it gets me an error of `"Cannot set property 'email' of undefined"`

```js
viewUser(){
    this.user.email=localStorage.getItem('email');
    this.userService.getProfile(this.user).subscribe(data=>this.loggedInUser=data);
  }
```

On the server side everything works fine and the data is also stored in the localstore.
I've tried everything to store the user globally but noting really works.

Edit: I'm trying to use the email of the user which I'm getting from the login mask to get all the information of the user from the server using another component.

Comment: In order to set email on user in NavbarComponent, this.user has to be an object, is it set to and object or is it undefined

Comment: Where do you get the data for `user`?

Comment: It is defined as a variable in the LoginComponent but It's actiually setting the Item, I saw it in the localstorage.

Comment: @MilesLelek is the `user` property defined in the navbar component?

Comment: No the user in the navbarcomponent is undefined. I just declared it.

Comment: @MilesLelek I see.. Is it still showing the same error then?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `user` is undefined at the very point when `viewUser()` is called.

On your navbar component, you should ensure that user is at least initialised as an empty object, or an object with some default properties/values. If there is an interface, you can do something like this

```
user: User = {
  email: undefined
}
```

Comment: No the data within the user comes from the login mask. I'm trying to use the email to get all the information of the user from the server from another component.

Comment: Oh yes now I get it, the user includes "constraints" so every variable has to be set so i changed it to String because it's just an email. Thank You!

Comment: @MilesLelek Yup! You will need to define it if not you won't be able to access the property.

Answer (score 0):

Define `user` first.

```
user:User = new User
```

and then,

```
viewUser(){
  this.user.email=localStorage.getItem('email');
  this.userService.getProfile(this.user).subscribe(data=>this.loggedInUser=data);
}
```